# Titles not properly encoded in the /posts/<id>/ajax-load-mini?title=true route

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh, xss

The route used to refresh the question after live update notifications doesn't properly encode the question title, which likely provides a limited opportunity for script injection.

In a more practical and less malicious scenario, it also causes the title to be updated incorrectly:

[image: incorrectly updated title]

You can see in the source of the [route's response to a different question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/131228/ajax-load-mini?title=true) that the unencoded quotation mark prematurely terminates the `data-title` attribute used to return the title text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks - a fix will be deployed shortly.